# Calling for a function within a function from another class returns "0"

Tags: php, class, function

```
<?php
class Kunde 
{
    public $knr;
    public $navn;
    public $adr;
    public $tlfnr;
    public $kurv = array();

    function __construct($nr,$n,$a)
    {
        $this->knr = $nr;
        $this->navn = $n;
        $this->adr = $a;
    }

    function LeggTilVare($vnavn,$vantall,$vpris)
    {
        $this->kurv[]=new Vare($vnavn,$vantall,$vpris);
    }

    function VisVarer()
    {
        for($i=0; $i < count($this->kurv); $i++)
        {
            $text+= $this->kurv[$i]->getInfo() . "<br/>";
        }

        return $text;
    }

class Vare 
{
    public $varenavn;
    public $antall;
    public $pris;

    function __construct($navn,$antall,$pris)
    {
        $this->varenavn=$navn;
        $this->antall=$antall;
        $this->pris=$pris;
    }

    function getInfo()
    {
        return $this->varenavn.", ".$this->antall." st, ".$this->pris.",-";
    }
}

$kunde1 = new Kunde(1,"Andreas","Gronland");

$kunde1->LeggTilVare("Kjekks", 10, 10.00);
```

I'm used to programming in Java but am now learning PHP.

My function `VisVarer()` will just return `"0"` and nothing else. I guess it has to do with the call for `getInfo()` inside another function from another class, or somethings wrong with my for-loop.

Maybe this is the wrong way to program something like this?

```
echo $kunde1->kurv[0]->getInfo(); // returns "Kjekks, 10 st, 10"

echo $kunde1->VisVarer(); // returns "0"
```

Comment: First things first, which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I like PHP, but I never understood why it uses a period for concatenation.... What's the 'point'? *Badum tss*

Comment: @Quasdunk because PHP it's a loosely typed language so the difference between adding two numbers and concatenating two strings can't be made only based on the data types

Comment: @mishu Ok, that actually makes sense, I guess... But there might have been other, more elegant and intuitive ways to solve this issue.

Comment: @Quasdunk maybe.. but maybe it could also get to cases like the ones you meet in javascript where if you don't use functions like parseInt you could see that 1+1 = 11 :)

Comment: btw.. I am still wondering if anyone knows why my answer was downvoted.. I am ready to update it if there is something wrong about it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php the concatenation operator is the dot 
In this line:

```
$text+= $this->kurv[$i]->getInfo() . "<br/>";
```

you are using the one you are used to from java (+=) and also the php specific one, the dot

try changing that line (and all those similar) to

```
$text .= $this->kurv[$i]->getInfo() . "<br/>";
```

Comment: anyway.. another recommendation would be to initialize your $text variable.. it is a good habit in general and in this case it prevents notices from appearing if `count($this->kurv)` is 0

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `+=` operator when you should use the `.=` operator for string concatenation.

In PHP, these are two different operations, mathematical addition and string concatenation.

Comment: You're right. Sometimes confusing learning many languages at once. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using this operator:

```
+=
```

That's only used for integers. PHP will try to turn the string into an integer (which ends up being 0).

Instead, you probably want the string concatenation operator:

```
.=
```

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is done with `.`, not `+`.

As such, you want to do `.=` instead of `+=` in `VisVarer`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to

```
$text.= $this->kurv[$i]->getInfo() . "<br/>";
```

the concatenation assign operator in PHP is `.=` not `+=`. What is happening is that you are adding as a number the resulting string to `$text` so it will always be zero.